# Using RewriteRule to redirect any request to PHP script without external redirects

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wampserver

I use `WampServer` (Apache/PHP/MySQL) and I have the following files in my `www` directory:

- `www` [dir]

  - `test` [dir]
  - `index.php` [file]
  - `.htaccess` [file]

I want to pass all URI requests as a parameter to `index.php` without causing any external redirects (location changes in client browser). So I tried to use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [nocase,qsappend,end]
```

Which works quite good, except when the URI is `/test`, in which case an external redirect changes the location to:

```
/test/?path=test
```

How can I make sure the external redirect does NOT happen even if the directory of the same name as the URI exists?

---

**Expected result:**

- Original URI request: `/test`
- Internal redirect: `index.php?path=test`
- External redirect: none

**Actual result:**

- Original URI request: `/test`
- Internal redirect: `index.php?path=test`
- External redirect: `/test/?path=test`

The ideal solution would be universal and would not apply only to `test` directory, but to any directory.

Comment: Put your code into a Virtual Host [See here for how to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just tried that and it made no difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem seems to be a conflict between `mod_rewrite` and `mod_dir`. Possible solutions are:

1. Disable `mod_dir`
2. [Put this to `.htaccess`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803362/298609):

   ```
   <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectorySlash Off
   </IfModule>
   ```

For more details about how `mod_rewrite` and `mod_dir` interact, [this answer has some excellent info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3273451/298609). And why the external redirect is necessary is [explained in docs (Trailing Slash Problem)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html#url).

---

**Related links**

- [DirectorySlash documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)
- [More mod_rewrite/mod_dir shenanigans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683335/298609)